# Facebook application not showing in application browser resulting in Fb:request-form unsuccessful

Tags: facebook

I have created an application but my application is not displayed when a user searches for my application.

How can my application will be listed and he can add application to his profile so that he can invite friends using Fb:request-form method?

I am using php and referring  http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:request-form#Examples

Answer (score 0):

Submit it to the [application directory](https://www.facebook.com/applications/). Also, you might look into getting your app [verified](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/).

Answer (score 0):

Applications are not listed in the [directory](https://www.facebook.com/applications/) until you register for it.  You can do so from your application page in the Developer app.

User's can add your application even if it is not listed, so don't fret too badly.  Obviously, listing is a pre-requisite for widespread adoption.